# Showing Proj $R[x,y]/(x^2)$ is not affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

So I started reading the [Proj construction.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M3)  I wanted to get more understanding by consider the graded ring

$$\frac{R[x,y]}{(x^2)}$$

where $x,y$ have degree $1$. Let $X= Proj(R[x,y]/(x^2))$. 
So I want to know if

(i) The scheme is not reduced.

(ii) The scheme is not affine.

---

For (i) I believe it is not so, since 
$$O_X(D_+(y))= (R[x,y]/(x^2))_{(y)} \simeq R[a]/(a^2) $$ 
is not reduced ring. But how does one show that is not affine?

Comment: I believe it is affine. Proj (R[x,y]) is covered by two charts $D_+(x)$ and $D_+(y)$. So, $X$ is covered by $X \cap  D_+(x)$ and $X \cap D_+(y)$. However, $X \cap D_+(x) = \emptyset$, $X = X \cap D_+(y)$, and you showed that the latter is affine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scheme is not reduced, but it is affine (more or less by accident - more variables would give you a projective and not affine scheme). This scheme is $V(x^2)\subset \Bbb P^1_R$, which is a fat $R$-point, and which has as it's reduction $V(x)\subset \Bbb P^1_R$, just an $R$-point, or $\operatorname{Spec} R$. As a scheme who's reduction is affine is again affine, $V(x^2)\subset \Bbb P^1_R$ is also an affine scheme - in particular, it's $\operatorname{Spec} R[x]/(x^2)$.

If you increased the number of variables, then you would not end up with an affine scheme - for example, $\operatorname{Proj} R[x,y,z]/(x^2)$ is a nonreduced $\Bbb P^1_R$ which is not affine. Dimension zero projective schemes are also affine (and thus finite), and correspond to $\operatorname{Proj}$ of dimension-one rings, like the one you've used here.

Comment: Thanks! There are a few terms which I don't understand and will search up.

Comment: I mean it might be worth pointing out that proper (which is less strong than projective)+affine is EQUIVALENT to finite.